# python pynput ERROR: failed to acquire X connection: Bad display name ""', DisplayNameError('')

Tags: python, database, keyboard, pynput

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/boot/system/key.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 76, in backend
    raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format(
ImportError: this platform is not supported: ('failed to acquire X connection: Bad display name ""', DisplayNameError(''))

Try one of the following resolutions:

 * Please make sure that you have an X server running, and that the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly
```

i what to RUN my python script but i get this Error when i trying to run using root user  or sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone gets this error so I get answer:

use this command in the terminal:
if you have this

> echo $DISPLAY
> :1

then do this or visa versa

> DISPLAY=":0" python3 filename.py